# Conditionally bind to two different commands in Xamarin XAML MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Here is the data template for my list view

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Command1, Source={x:Reference Name=MainNavigationPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Property_A_Integer}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Command2, Source={x:Reference Name=MainNavigationPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Property_B_Enum}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

Property_B_Enum is of type `MyEnum`

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    None,
    Fruit,
    Veggies,
    Meat,
    Cookie
}
```

In the code above, there are two gesture recognizers.  When the list view gets bound to the VM, the items come in via the ItemsSource.  Some of the items have Property_B_Enum set to "None".  When that happens, I'd like the first gesture recognizer be there, not the second. And vice versa.

This feels like a good use for a Trigger, but I'm not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a data template selector to do this.

Have 2 templates one with Command1 , one with Command2 and use the template selector to display one or the other depending on Property_B_Enum

[More details here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/)

Edit

[These are slightly better instructions](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/)

Or you could pass the whole Item in the command parameter and put the logic to grab the correct property in the Command handler

Comment: The sample on that site is a little incomplete, but I figured it out (There was no SetupDataTemplates() function defined there.  The sample code has it, but it also defeats the purpose of declaring the item templates in XAML)  So I fixed it by not having a SetupDataTemplates and loaded the resources from the dictionary like so:  `DataTemplate myTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["my_resource_key"];` and I put this in the ContentPage's constructor - where SetupDataTemplates() was in the sample.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. You can do it all in the XAML except for the DataTemplateSelector class. I have added a link to hopefully better instructions in the answer.

Comment: Thank you.  Those were better.  BTW -- you might consider re-stating some of the code from those instructions so that it's all right here in the SO posting.  Sometimes links disappear after a couple years.